# bigquery code not translating Guillemets « and » correctly

Tags: google-bigquery

The following bigquery code does not display correctly Guillemets « and ». In the output of the code below, notice that the Guillements are 'translated' as xAB and xBB. The expected answer should preserve the current translation but replace xAB with « and xBB with  ».

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  decode(word string) AS ((
    SELECT
    IF
      (STARTS_WITH(word, '&#x'),
        safe.code_points_to_STRING(ARRAY(
          SELECT
            ifnull(SAFE_CAST(value AS int64),
              ASCII(value))
          FROM
            UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(word, '&#', '0'),';')) value
          WHERE
            NOT value = '' )),
        word) ));
WITH
  DATA AS (
  SELECT
    'Arabic' AS lang,
    'https://www.elwatannews.com/news/details/5516935' AS url,
    `'&#x62A;&#x637;&#x648;&#x631;&#x627;&#x62A; &#xAB;&#x645;&#x630;&#x628;&#x62D;&#x629; &#x623;&#x628;&#x648; &#x62D;&#x632;&#x627;&#x645; &#xBB;.. &#x62F;&#x641;&#x646; 10 &#x62C;&#x62B;&#x62B; &#x648;&#x636;&#x628;&#x637; 19 &#x645;&#x646; &#x639;&#x627;&#x626;&#x644;&#x62A;&#x64A; &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x62C;&#x632;&#x631;&#x629;'` AS title)
SELECT
  url,
  lang,
  (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(decode(chars), ''
    ORDER BY
    OFFSET
      )
  FROM
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(title, r'(?:&#x.{3};)+|[^&]+')) chars
  WITH
  OFFSET
    ) AS translate
FROM
  DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  decode(word string) AS ((
    SELECT
    IF
      (STARTS_WITH(word, '&#x'),
        safe.code_points_to_STRING(ARRAY(
          SELECT
            ifnull(SAFE_CAST(value AS int64),
              ASCII(value))
          FROM
            UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(word, '&#', '0'),';')) value
          WHERE
            NOT value = '' )),
        word) ));
WITH
  DATA AS (
  SELECT
    'Arabic' AS lang,
    'https://www.elwatannews.com/news/details/5516935' AS url,
    '&#x62A;&#x637;&#x648;&#x631;&#x627;&#x62A; &#xAB;&#x645;&#x630;&#x628;&#x62D;&#x629; &#x623;&#x628;&#x648; &#x62D;&#x632;&#x627;&#x645; &#xBB;.. &#x62F;&#x641;&#x646; 10 &#x62C;&#x62B;&#x62B; &#x648;&#x636;&#x628;&#x637; 19 &#x645;&#x646; &#x639;&#x627;&#x626;&#x644;&#x62A;&#x64A; &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x62C;&#x632;&#x631;&#x629;' AS title)
SELECT
  # url,
  lang,
  (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(decode(chars), ''
    ORDER BY
    OFFSET
      )
  FROM
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(title, r'(?:&#x.{2,3};)+|[^&]+')) chars
  WITH
  OFFSET
    ) AS translate
FROM
  DATA
```

with output

[image]